# How to zip Rose Trees in Haskell

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, tree

For a Haskell Tic Tac Toe game, I am trying to zip two Rose Trees. I have defined the rose tree as

```
data Rose a = a :> [Rose a]
```

I have tried the following:

```
zipTrees :: Rose Board -> Rose Int -> Rose (Board, Int)
zipTrees (b :> []) (i :> []) = (b,i) :> []
zipTrees (b :> chib) (i :> chii) = (b, i) :> zipTrees chib chii
```

but an error occurs, because it couldn't match expected type `Rose Int` and `Rose Board` with `[Rose Int]` and `[Rose Board]` respectively. I am clueless about how to zip the trees in any other way.

To illustrate further, if I wanted to zip the trees

```
a :> [a :> [a :> []], a :> []]
```

and `b :> [b :> [b :> []], b :> []]`, I want to return the tree

```
(a, b) :> [(a, b) :> [(a, b) :> []], (a,b) :> []]
```

Comment: What should happen if the trees have different shapes?  e.g. `a :> [a :> [], a :> []]` with `b  :> [b :> [b :> []]]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`chib` and `chii` are lists of trees, not trees themselves. You can't just call `zipTrees` on them. You will need to either recurse

```
zipTrees :: Rose Board -> Rose Int -> Rose (Board, Int)
zipTrees (b :> [])       (i :> _)        = …
zipTrees (b :> _)        (i :> [])       = …
zipTrees (b :> (cb:cbs)) (i :> (ci:cis)) = …
```

or just use [`zipWith`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:zipWith)

```
zipTrees :: Rose Board -> Rose Int -> Rose (Board, Int)
zipTrees (b :> chib) (i :> chii) = (b, i) :> zipWith zipTrees chib chii
--                                           ^^^^^^^
```